# Insert Rows and columns in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code

```
row, col = image.shape
print image
for x in range(row):
  for y in range(col):
    image = np.insert(image, [x,y], values=0, axis=1)
print image
```

I get this error when I run my code,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\Code.py", line 55, in <module>
    expand(img1)
  File "C:\...\Code.py", line 36, in expand
    image = np.insert(image, [x,y], values=0, axis=1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 3627, in insert
    new[slobj2] = arr
ValueError: array is not broadcastable to correct shape
```

What I would like the function to do is given an array of size i,j it inserts a row and column of zero's between each row and column.

so if I have

```
`array([[1,2,3], 
        [4,5,6],
        [7,8,9]])`
```

the function would return a result of

```
[1,0,2,0,3,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0]
[4,0,5,0,6,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0]
[7,0,8,0,9,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

I have also tried,

```
row, col = image.shape
for x in range(row):
  image = np.insert(image, x, values=0, axis=1)
for y in range(col):
  image = np.insert(image, y, values=0, axis=1)
```

But I do not get the result I am looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Avoid `insert` and other functions that modify the shape of the array gradually - these types of functions are generally quite slow in NumPy. Instead, preallocate and fill:

```
newimage = np.zeros((row*2, col*2))
newimage[::2,::2] = image
```

Comment: Could you explain how the syntax in the second line works?

Comment: It sets every second row and column to the corresponding values from `image` using NumPy’s extended slice notation.

Answer (score 1):

`np.insert` lets you specify multiple insert points.  Check its help

```
image=np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)
image=np.insert(image,[1,2,3],0,0)
image=np.insert(image,[1,2,3],0,1)
```

produces

```
array([[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [7, 0, 8, 0, 9, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

`np.insert` does the preallocate and fill trick, but with more generality.

In my time tests `nneonneo's` `[::2,::2]` insert approach is quite a bit faster - 10-30x.  But it might be harder to generalize.  The use of `np.insert` isn't bad - I get 300ms times for a 1000x1000 array.

Indexing with 2 slices is faster.  A more general advanced indexing using `np.ix_` is slower, though still 2-3x faster than `np.insert`.

```
newimage = np.zeros((2*N,2*N))
ii = np.arange(0,2*N,2)
newimage[np.ix_(ii,ii)] = image
```

Comment: With advanced indexing you could probably make the preallocate-and-fill approach generalizable.